# .htaccess redirect sub-folders to the correspondent index.php

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

How can I redirect each request for a subfolder to the index.php in the same folder

```
myserver.com/folder/subfolder1/test   redirected to   folder/subfolder1/index.php
myserver.com/folder/subfolder2/test   redirected to   folder/subfolder2/index.php
...
```

I added a .htaccess for each sub folder like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

I would like to redirect them with one .htaccess in the parent folder :

```
Folder/
        .htaccess    <-- one redirection here
        subfolder1/
                index.php
        subfolder2/
                index.php
        subfolder3/
                index.php
          ...  

        subfolder n /
                index.php
```

P.S. : all the sub-folders are with different names and do not follow a naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly in the root `.htaccess` file. (This defaults to `index.html`, although many distros include `index.php` as well, so you often don't need to do anything!)

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This tells Apache (mod_dir) to look for an `index.php` file in the requested directory (note the relative URL-path) when you request the directory directly.

If the `DirectoryIndex` document (ie. `index.php`) is not found then you will get a 403 Forbidden (assuming mod_autoindex is enabled and directory listings are disabled, ie. `Options -Indexes`).

There is nothing more you need to add. (Unless you actually want an "external redirect"?!)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
> ```

You do not need to use mod_rewrite. In fact, this rule won't do anything here anyway, since the 2nd *condition* explicitly excludes requests to directories.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/.*$ $1/index.php [L,QSA]
```

I've found the answer , with this rule every folder is redirected to it index.php if the file does not exist.